# Flot graphs tick issue

Tags: javascript, algorithm, flot

I have a `flot` graphs with a custom tick formatter function,

```
if ((val / 1000) >= 1) {
    val = String(Math.round(val / 1000)) + 'K';
}

return String(val);
```

But the issue is it returns same values for some ticks.

Little explanation about code:

```
val --> any integer value ranging from 1 to infinity
```

`val / 1000` logic is to convert the tick into user friends (readable) format (1K, 2K etc).

But the issue here is I get repeated tick labels when some `val` round up to equal values.

It want to know any good way to fix this algorithm to calculate this?

### Addendum

`val / 1000` does not mean val is multiple of `1000` it could be any integer value ranging from 1 to infinity.

Eg: For `val = 1000 or 1001` it return `1K` on two tick labels.

I know its algorithmic bug .I just wanna to know if there is any way to fix it cleanly

### Notes

1. Ticks must be rounding to two decimal at the most (great if no decimal points).
2. You cannot change `val / 1000`. You can Play round with `Math.round()` function.
3. Even if want to use `toFixed()` follow Rule 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses suffixes for large numbers while keeping the accuracy:

```
function tick_label(val) {
    if (val < 0) return "\u2212" + tick_label(-val);
    if (val < 1000) return String(val);

    var mag = 1;
    var suffix = "";

    if (val >= 1000) { mag = 1000; suffix = "k" }
    if (val >= 1000000) { mag = 1000000; suffix = "M" }
    if (val >= 1000000000) { mag = 1000000000; suffix = "G" }

    var div = mag;

    while (val % 10 == 0) {
        val /= 10;
        div /= 10;
    }

    return String(val / div) + suffix;
}
```

This code relies on round numbers for ticks, so that the exact number doesn't look strange or overly exact. (A scale of 1.002k, 1.004k, 1.006k looks okay, but a scale of 1.102k, 1.202k, 1.302k does not. I'm not familiar with Flot, but I guess it takes care of that.)

Comment: @Pilot: Yes, but does this value really occur on the axis? If you want a better heuristic, you should provide all axis labels or at least the upper and lower bound plus the step. I think you want each label to be as "rounded" as possible, but different from all other labels. If you have labels like 1000, 1002, 1004 you can then choose to print them as 1,000; 1,002; 1004: Just return the appropriate string early when `val % 10`. (But then, 1k; 1,002; 1,004 also looks odd to read. In my opinion, natural-looking labelling is a matter of both the printing function and choosing a good scale.)

Comment: exact catch Oehm..I want each label to be as "rounded" as possible, but different from all other labels.What do you suggest.And there is no way to specify customize the step in flot graph.

Comment: @Pilot: As I said, I'm not familiar with Flot, but a quick look at the API doc (https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) indicates that you can pass ticks and labels as array: `[[1000, "1,000"], [1002, "1,002"], [1004, "1,004"]]` Then you can determine all tick marks yourself and also decide on a proper formatting. (Looks like you can also generate the ticks plus format with a function.) Might that be a solution?

Comment: @M oehm Thats what exactly did..I created custom tick formatter function posted in question and returned readable ticks

Comment: @Pilot: How can I know what you did? You haven't posted a function, just some statements. Looks like you wrote a `tickFormatter`, whereas the array would be the `ticks`. Without knowing what the chart and the labels look like and what exaclty you have done, I can't give you a better solution.

Comment: Sorry but My Question starts with ***I have a flot graphs with a custom tick formatter function..***

Comment: @Pilot M Oehm didn't suggest a tick formatter; he suggested providing a tick array, which is a valid solution to the problem.

Comment: @DNS but sir tick array contents are dynamic .So I cannot hardcode it.@DNS Please suggest me good solution...You are the last hope

Comment: @Pilot That doesn't really matter.  The code that Flot uses to generate ticks is not very complex; you can always write your own loop over the values, find the min/max, then generate an array of evenly-spaced values to use as your ticks.

Comment: @DNS is not actually the issue with flot..Its actually an algorithmic flaw..I just need to make sure my tick formatter would always give non repeated ticks for any input and in readable format like 1k, 2k etc

Comment: @DNS: I must resist commenting on your pathetic begging and insulting, but don't you see the problem here: If you want your custom formatter to provide a solution that is different for all ticks, the formatter must know what all other tick values are. A good solution might scan all values, determine the least common number of zeroes in the end, decide on a common format and then format all ticks in one go. The `ticks` array is a way to do it. It is not hard-coded; you can update it whenever you update your axis. The documentation says that `ticks` can be a function that generates the array.

Comment: @MOehm I dont understand **pathetic begging and insulting** ??